# Is it possible to give other players the ability to use my powertools?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

Can I give other players the use of my powertools with the EssentialsX plugin for Bukkit? Not the ability to use the /powertool command, but the usage of my premade powertools.

Example: I make a fireball staff and the players cannot use /powertool themselves, but have to buy my powertools such as the fireball staff.

Answer (score 1):

## You can't.

`/powertool` bindings are per-player, so handing someone else a stick that you added fireball effects to will only work for you, regardless of them having permissions or not.

For someone else to use it, they will have to redo the set of `/powertool append XXXX` or `/powertool [name]` command(s) you used. Also, you can't reuse multiple command sets on the same item type; ie. a fireball stick and a lightning stick.

tl;dr Not supported.